# Generated ext4 filesystem fails to copy correctly a big file

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

I'm using Buildroot to generate a Linux system for an embedded device. It build all the system in a "target" directory and then call mke2fs to generate a filesystem from this "target" directory.

The filesystem is ~16GB, and it should contain one big file of ~12GB. When I try to use the generated filesystem, this file seems to be somehow corrupt. It cannot be used (the program that must read it fails to do it) and using the file explorer or 'df' command, the free space of the filesystem seems to be ~92% (but 12GB of the total 16GB should be used by this single file!). Looking to the properties of the file with the file explorer, it still says that its size is ~12GB, but 'du' command says it is 622MiB.

The original file is OK in "target" directory. 'du' says its 12G and the program reads it OK. If I copy it to the generated filesystem (with 'cp' or 'scp') then the file can be read and the disk usage is the correct one.

I don't have any problems with any file other than this one.

I've tried to generate the filesystem myself, with `mkfs.ext4 -d target fs.ext4 15192M` and I have the same problem.

Comment: Did you mount the generated filesystem on your PC yet? Have you run `fsck` on it?

Comment: Yes, I've used it in the device but also mounting it in my PC. fsck doesn't report any errors.